# Bootstrap4でハンバーガーメニューの色を変更したい

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrap4のハンバーガーメニューについてなんですが

```
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

このクラスに対してデフォルトの色から白色に変更をしたいため

```
span.navbar-toggler-icon {
  color:#fff;
}
```

とかいているんですが色が白色になりません。

この色を変更するにはどうしたら適用されるでしょうか？

こちらdropboxにアップロードした問題点のイメージ画像になります。
[image: 問題のハンバーガーメニュー]

Comment: 参考: 英語版SOでの類似質問 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/42586729/2322778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずHTMLのコード内で、`<span>..</span>`をラップしているボタンにカスタム用のクラス`custom-hamburger`を追加します。

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark custom-hamburger">
　　　　<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</nav>
```

CSSで`custom-hamburger`内の`navbar-toggler-icon`に対し、カスタム用の色を指定します。
Bootstrap4ではSVGを使っているので以下のように`background-image`の設定を使います。`stroke=white`というように`white`に設定しているため、白いハンバーガーになります。

```
 .custom-hamburger .navbar-toggler-icon{
  　　　　background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='white' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Comment: 回答されていた通りにやってみたところ色は白色に変わりませんでした。

Comment: この部分以外のCSSは変更が反映されますか？

Comment: @PicoSushi  背景の色やボーダーなどは変更が反映されるんですがハンバーガーのみ変更が適用されません。

Comment: @t.s `span`以外の部分は何がありますか？

Comment: @kabichan     '<nav>' '<a>' '</a>'  '<button>' '<span>' '</span>' '</button>'
となっています。

Comment: すみません、私が間違えました。`css`の順番を変えてみてください。ボタンの中にカスタム用のクラスがあると思いますので、`.custom-hamburger .navbar-toggler-icon{
  background-image: ...
}` にするとどうなりますか？（`custom-hamburger`を先に持ってくる）

Comment: 順番をご指摘された通りに変えてみたところ
うまくハンバーガーの部分がデフォルトの色から
白色に変更できることができました。
優先度の関係でスタイルが適用されなかったと
ゆうことなんでしょうか？

Comment: はい、`custom-hamburger`を先に置くことにより、これが親要素であり、その子要素である`navbar-toggler-icon`に対してこのスタイルを適用するという記述になります。

Comment: もし解決したようでしたら、回答を承認して頂けますとありがたいです。そうすることにより、この問題は解決済みになります。